# How to start User Accounts on startup?

Tags: startup, startup-applications, init

I have to run the application `User Accounts` on Startup (log in), but I do not manage to add it to Startup Applications.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*User accounts* normally appears as part of the System Settings (System Settings > User Accounts).

To open it specifically from command line, you have to add either the command:

```
gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

or

```
unity-control-center user-accounts
```

on Ubuntu **14.04**, or

```
unity-control-center user-accounts
```

on **15.04+**

to Startup Applications.

Comment: Thank you!! but i have unity control center, so i only change the command.